# How to maintain count of html container elements and send to Servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have parent-child relation between html elements `test-case` & `step-container` such that one test case can have multiple steps when user clicks on add `+Step` and there is also button for adding `+TestCase`.

User first has to create `TestCase` and add one or more `Steps` to that. Both `test-case` & `step-container` are enclosed by parent `test-case-container`.

**In JSP:**

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <form action="./AddTestCases" method="post"><button id="test" name="test-btn" value="1">ADD TEST CASE</button></form>
</div>

<form class="from-class" action="./AddTestCases" method="post">

  <div id="tc-001" class="test-case-container">

    <div class="test-case">
      <div>
        <label for="tc-name-001" class="test-case-label">TC001</label>
        <button id="tc-delete-001" name="tc-delete-001" class="test-case-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
      </div>
      <textarea id="tc-name-001" name="tc-name-001" class="test-case-name" rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Test Case Name"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="step-container">
      <div>
        <label for="step-name-001" class="step-num-label">Step 1</label>
        <button id="step-delete-001" name="step-delete-001" class="step-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
      </div>
      <textarea id="step-name-001" name="step-name-001" class="step-desc" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Step Description"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="step" value="ADD STEP">
    <button id="done" value="DONE">DONE</button>

  </div>

  <button id="save">SAVE</button>

</form>
```

I am collecting this data using a `from` and sending it to a `Servlet` for processing.

The question is, how do I keep the count to how many `Steps`each `TestCase` has before I send post request to a servlet. I want something like:

```
{
'tc-01': 2,
'tc-02': 3,
'tc-03': 5,
}
```

And then send this with/before data so that I can further process it depending on number of steps for each test case has.

Comment: can you use jquery as well ?

Comment: not familiar with jquery but Javascript i can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For keeping count of div under your `TestCase` you can get all the class with `name ="test-case-container"` then we can loop through this to get count of `steps` and then finally add that to array .

**Demo Code**  :

```js
var test = new Array(); //frov creating array of object[{},{}]
var test2 = {} //or for creating objects only { ,, }

function add() {
//getting div with class ="test-case-container"
  const tests = document.querySelectorAll('.test-case-container');
  tests.forEach(function(e) {
  //getting id of div
    var ids = e.getAttribute('id');
    //getting count of div under the main div 
    var count = e.getElementsByClassName("step-container").length;
    item = {}
    item[ids] = count;
    test.push(item); //adding item to array
    test2[ids] = count;
  });
  console.log(test) //array of objects [ {} ,{}]
  console.log(test2) //objects { ,, }

  //ajax call to send the array 
  //or submit the form adding these in hidden inputs
}
```

```html
<div id="tc-001" class="test-case-container">

  <div class="test-case">
    <div>
      <label for="tc-name-001" class="test-case-label">TC001</label>
      <button id="tc-delete-001" name="tc-delete-001" class="test-case-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="tc-name-001" name="tc-name-001" class="test-case-name" rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Test Case Name"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="step-container">
    <div>
      <label for="step-name-001" class="step-num-label">Step 1</label>
      <button id="step-delete-001" name="step-delete-001" class="step-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="step-name-001" name="step-name-001" class="step-desc" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Step Description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="step-container">
    <div>
      <label for="step-name-001" class="step-num-label">Step 1</label>
      <button id="step-delete-001" name="step-delete-001" class="step-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="step-name-001" name="step-name-001" class="step-desc" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Step Description"></textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" id="step" value="ADD STEP">
  <button id="done" value="DONE">DONE</button>

</div>
<div id="tc-002" class="test-case-container">

  <div class="test-case">
    <div>
      <label for="tc-name-002" class="test-case-label">TC002</label>
      <button id="tc-delete-002" name="tc-delete-002" class="test-case-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="tc-name-002" name="tc-name-002" class="test-case-name" rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Test Case Name"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="step-container">
    <div>
      <label for="step-name-002" class="step-num-label">Step 1</label>
      <button id="step-delete-002" name="step-delete-001" class="step-del" style="margin-left: 16rem;">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <textarea id="step-name-002" name="step-name-001" class="step-desc" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Step Description"></textarea>
  </div>


  <input type="submit" id="step" value="ADD STEP">
  <button id="done" value="DONE">DONE</button>

</div>

<button id="save" onclick="add()">SAVE</button>
                      <!--added onclick-->
```

Then , you can either put this array to some hidden `inputs` and then submit your form or you can send these data using `ajax` to your servlet .